# Android Library layouts using main app drawables

Tags: android, android-library

I have an app that needs to be branded for a couple of different companies.

So basically, the functionality stays the same but each company has their own colours and logos.

I've been able to do this by having a library that contains pretty much everything, including the layouts, and then each company app is a separate application that contains all of the drawables (images) for that company, and it links to the library.

The problem is that I currently have to keep a set of the drawables with the library, even though those images will never be used. If I remove them, the library project gets the dreaded big red X on the layouts.

Is there a way to tell the library that the drawables are in the main app?

Or is it ok to leave that set of drawables - will they automatically be excluded from the built apk if the main app already has them?

Thanks,
-Nico

Comment: I'm thinking along the same lines as you. I don't want many drawables/values in the lib where the only purpose is to be overridden in the dependant Apps. I'm looking around to see if there is an 'abstract' resource ref that can be defined in the lib that must be implemented in the App